# MySQL crash recovery how to recover the datas

Tags: mysql, crash, xampp, innodb, vps

I am using a VPS and suddenly it was stopped and when it came live MySQL server didn't start. I searched for the errors and it was due to the Innodb. I backed up all the data files and downloaded to my local computer and have replaced the local computer Mysql data with the crashed db. But I got the following errors. Please help me to fix it.

```
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-09-06 09:20:34 c8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-09-06 09:20:34 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 561264227
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-09-06 09:20:35 6940 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups uses space ID: 7 at filepath: .\phpmyadmin\pma_usergroups.ibd. Cannot open tablespace roundcube/cache_messages which uses space ID: 7 at filepath: .\roundcube\cache_messages.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\roundcube\cache_messages.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

MySql configuration files of XAMPP

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# F:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is F:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.
#innodb_force_recovery = 1 
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "F:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "F:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "F:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "F:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "F:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "F:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "F:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "F:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "F:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "F:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="F:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though you are not receiving errors related to the database itself being corrupted but rather you are receiving a large amount of configuration based errors.

You will need to clear each of these configuration issues first before we can properly assist you.

I would start first by correcting version specific errors.

I would also advise(if at all possible) you grab your old configuration files to make comparisons against, unless the two OS's you are migrating from / to are exactly the alike. It is highly unlikely you will be able to copy/paste the configuration files, but it will at least give you a better starting point.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I don't have the configuration files of old mysql server. I can provide you the xampp configuration file.

Comment: Though helpful, it's not completely necessary to have the old config files. Like I said, fixing the version specific errors first will at least help you get in the write direction. I have faced a similar issue in the past, in my case, I fixed versioning errors and ran into a lock tables issues. Using --no-lock with mysqldump solved my problem(Though doubtful this may end the same way mine did)

Comment: Could you please specify in details please. How to use --no-lock with mysqldump.

Comment: You can achieve no lock with the following `mysqldump --lock-tables=false ...` but in regards to InnoDB, it is recommended to use `--single-transaction` instead

Comment: Where shall i use this, in configuration files or else?

Comment: mysqldump is a tool used on a command line(Though it can be ran from within most languages as well via system,execs and so on. This is all going to take some research. You're error is a lenght one and will require some time and effort to fully take care of.

Comment: Tables `phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups` and `roundcube\cache_messages` share same space id - 7. That never must happen, although both tablespaces are not necessary corrupt. No config option can cause that. I'd rather think some tablespace was copied from another instance.